# Have multiple "show detail" segues for a master detail iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, master-detail

I have a Master-detail application. The 'master' part of the app has to be able to link to multiple types detail views (each with their own different view controller). How could it be possible to achieve this? (Is it even possible to do it? If not, what is the alternative?)

Here is my storyboard.

[image: Storyboard image]

Thank you for your help, and please don't hesitate to ask for some precisions if I was not very clear.

Comment: How would the user and/or app indicate it wants Full detail view vs. Second detail view? Is it based upon the cell type, or perhaps a property in the tableView or dataSource?

Comment: Thank you for your (very) fast response! It would be based on the `indexPath.row` property of the cell.

Comment: You could have two different prototype cells, one that is wired to First Detail View, and another that is wired to Second Detail View.  In `cellForRowAt` you'd pick the appropriate prototype cell based upon `indexPath.row` OR ...

Comment: ... you can wire the two segues from the viewController icon at the top of the VC instead of from the cell, give the segues appropriate identifiers such as `"segueToFirstDetailVC"` and `"segueToSecondDetailVC"` and in `didSelectRow` use `indexPath.row` to call the desired segue with `performSegue(withIdentifier)`.

Comment: Wow, ok. That was easy. Thank you very much! The first method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this:

1. You could have two different prototype cells, one that is wired to *First Detail View*, and another that is wired to *Second Detail View*. Each prototype cell would have its own unique identifier (such as `"firstDetailCell"` and `"secondDetailCell"`). In `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` you'd pick the appropriate prototype cell identifier based upon `indexPath.row` and pass that to `dequeueReuableCell(withIdentifier:)`.

   **OR**
2. You can wire the two segues from the `viewController` icon at the top of the viewController instead of from the cell, give the segues appropriate identifiers (such as `"segueToFirstDetailVC"` and `"segueToSecondDetailVC"`) and in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` use `indexPath.row` to call the desired segue with `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.